# Fullcalendar start end time from json feed

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm feeding fullcalendar from my custom php script via build in json feed functionality. But its little bit unclear for me, how i should prepare start and end times so it will display time in calendar.
Currently json feed responds following json data:

```
[{"id":46,"title":"Some Event","start":"2013-12-16 06:00:00"},
{"id":47,"title":"Some Event 2","start":"2013-12-23 06:00:00"},
{"id":48,"title":"Some Event3","start":"2013-12-30 06:00:00"}]
```

But fullcalendar does not understand time part from this start field.
fullcalendar documentation says taht time can be also in  format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z")

So i prepared my json data like this:

```
[{"id":46,"title":"Some event","start":"2013-12-16T06:00:00Z"},
{"id":47,"title":"Some event 2","start":"2013-12-23T06:00:00Z"},
{"id":48,"title":"Some event 3","start":"2013-12-30T06:00:00Z"}]
```

It didn't make any changes.
Any more ideas ?

Comment: Tried with unix timestamp, still nothing.

Comment: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/ have you `allDay : false`?

Comment: Thank you, it helped. Post it as an answer, then i can add you points what you deserve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array) says you have to use `allDay : false` to show the time:

```
{
    title  : 'event3',
    start  : '2010-01-09 12:30:00',
    allDay : false // will make the time show
}
```